# is this sentence correct? "do you remember me like I you" or "like i do you"

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Is this sentence correct? "do you remember me like I do you/ or like I you?" and what is it called in the English language?
what is the rule behind that and what is the correct structure. thank you.

Comment: It is called ellipsis. It is technically correct, but *"... like I you"* sounds a bit strange.

Comment: "...as I do you" would be more natural, if rather formal.